# Применение fxaa шейдера в ofx плагине

Tags: c++, opengl, шейдеры

Я пытаюсь добавить в ofx плагин fxaa шейдер, который должен сгладить изображение.

Проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю как передать в sampler2D информацию с экрана. Возможно мне нужно из буфера как то подтянуть информацию для дальнейшей проброски в шейдер или поступить как то по иному. К сожалению не хватает знаний для решения этой задачи.

Код в котором у меня затык:

```
glUseProgram(Program);

// set resolution
glUniform2f(Resolution, 1.f, 1.f);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
GLuint _texture0; // <=== how to get current texture? may be from buffer?
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture0);
// Texture unit 0 is for TDiffuse
glUniform1i(TDiffuse, 0);


// ! turn off shader program
glUseProgram(0);
```

Если будет необходимость я представлю весь код плагина.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы прибиндить текстуру необходимо задефайнить в настройках проекта OFX_SUPPORTS_OPENGLRENDER. Это необходимо для получения доступа к методам для работы с openGL.

Текстуру получить из нужного клипа следующим образом:

```
auto texture = _dstClip->loadTexture(args.time);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture->getIndex());
```

Так же можно это сделать так:

OfxPropertySetHandle source_texture = NULL;
    status = gOpenGLSuite->clipLoadTexture(myData->sourceClip, time, NULL, NULL, &sourceImg);

```
status = gPropHost->propGetInt(sourceImg, kOfxImageEffectPropOpenGLTextureIndex, 0, &source_texture_index);
status = gPropHost->propGetInt(sourceImg, kOfxImageEffectPropOpenGLTextureTarget, 0, &source_texture_target);
status = gPropHost->propGetString(sourceImg, kOfxImageEffectPropPixelDepth, 0, &tmps);

glEnable(source_texture_target);
glBindTexture(source_texture_target, source_texture_index);
glTexParameteri(source_texture_target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(source_texture_target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(source_texture_target, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(source_texture_target, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);

...

glEnd();

glDisable(source_texture_target);
gOpenGLSuite->clipFreeTexture(sourceImg);
```